# Object destructuring in VueJS v-slot on IE / Edge

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11, destructuring

Do you know a way to make object destructuring work on IE11?

Considering the following code:

```html
<list entity="ApplicationEntity" api-action="get_internal" v-slot="{item}">
    <list-column title="Name" ordering="name">
        ${ item.name }
    </list-column>
</list>
```

The `v-slot="{item}"` part doesn't work on IE (and even on old versions of edge).

To make it work I have to write:

```html
<list entity="ApplicationEntity" api-action="get_internal" v-slot:default="slotProps">
    <list-column title="Name" ordering="name">
        ${ slotProps.item.name }
    </list-column>
</list>
```

That is not a big deal, but in bigger templates it can make a significant difference on the readability.

One **important** note: the code above is part of a `twig` template, so the html is not part of the client build process.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

After debugging the VueJS source, I've seen the generated code.

If I write:

```html
<test v-slot="slotProps">
    ${ slotProps.item.toto }
</test>
```

The generated code is:

```js
_c('test',{scopedSlots:_u([{key:"default",fn:function(slotProps){return [_v(_s(slotProps.item.toto))]}}])})
```

And if I write:

```html
<test v-slot="{item}">
    ${ item.toto }
</test>
```

It gives:

```js
_c('test',{scopedSlots:_u([{key:"default",fn:function({item}){return [_v(_s(item.toto))]}}])})
```

So the difference comes down to:

```js
function(slotProps)
// vs
function({item})
```

I understand for IE11, but I don't for edge 20.

So if I try:

```js
function test(obj) {
    console.log(obj.item);
}

function test2({item}) {
    console.log(item);
}

test({item: 2});
test2({item: 2});
```

I got two time `2` in the console on Chrome, but nothing on IE11 or Edge 20.

Comment: As another community member had already informed you that the Destructuring assignment is not supported on IE. It is supported in Edge since version 14. You are using version 20 and it is not working. But I am not sure why you are using such an old version of Edge. I suggest you test the issue with the latest version Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0. You can also try to test the issue with  MS Edge Chromium browser. It is not recommended to use the too old version of the Edge browser.

Comment: I use the Edge installed with the IE11 VM provided by Microsoft. In the latest version of Edge it works, but the point was to test the compatibility because all the future users may not be on the latest version. Anyway, the issue is closed for me, I now know that there is no workaround because it's a core limitation of the js engine. The Edge 20 issue is a side question with not much importance because I have to change the syntax to support IE 11 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has never supported destructuring and there isn't a way to just "make it work". IE's JavaScript engine is incapable of reading code that uses this functionality. This is part of the reason why IE is so notoriously bad to have compatibility with nowadays. If you are producing a web app for a client that must use IE, you can't use destructuring and will have to rewrite your code to be compatible with IE.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response, so I will have to do with the limitation. I still wonder why it doesn't work on edge 20 while I can see on the mozilla's website that destructuring is supported since Edge 14.

Comment: That's a good question, Edge has generally been pretty good with compatibility.  I am not super familiar with Vue.js, but perhaps it could be that Edge is missing some compatibility elsewhere other than the destructuring that is causing similar symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `v-slot="{item}"` to `v-slot="{item: item}"`, that should work.
The reason is that IE does not support some of the new ECMAScript features like object destructing and that shorthand you wanted to use.

NOTE: `{ item: item }` is equivalent to `{ item }`, but it's just a shorthand when the object property has the same name as variable you want to assign.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work, even on Edge 20. Both notations should work on Edge 20, shouldn't they?